# VSCode No authentication providers are available

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, synchronization

I have just installed vscode on KDE NEON. Syncing does not work at all, even clicking on the Account-icon doesn't show the corresponding menu.

When I try to activate synchronization from within `Settings`, I get the following notificaiton:

> Error while turning on Settings Sync. No authentication providers are available.

Hier is the VScode inforamation

```
Version: 1.65.2
Commit: c722ca6c7eed3d7987c0d5c3df5c45f6b15e77d1
Date: 2022-03-10T15:36:26.048Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.13.0-35-generic snap
```

The logs of sync settings in VSCode:

```
[2022-03-19 10:37:36.671] [settingssync] [info] Using settings sync service https://vscode-sync.trafficmanager.net/
[2022-03-19 10:37:36.671] [settingssync] [info] Auto Sync is disabled.
```

when I try to call the website `https://vscode-sync.trafficmanager.net/` in browser, I get also an error

[image]

This behavior is repo-independent.

Any Idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

apparently it is a very fresh bug.
The solution was to install `gnome-keyring` and `libsecret` via synaptic package manager.

see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/144471

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem on arch linux {manjaro}
follow this
To install `gnome-keyring`, `libsecret`, and `libgnome-keyring` on Manjaro, you can use the `pamac` package manager or the terminal. Here's how to do it using `pamac`:

1. Open a terminal.
2. Update your system's package list and upgrade the packages (optional but recommended):

   ```
   sudo pamac update
   ```
3. Install `gnome-keyring` and `libsecret`:

   ```
   sudo pamac install gnome-keyring libsecret
   ```
4. Install `libgnome-keyring` from the AUR (Arch User Repository) using `pamac`:

   ```
   sudo pamac build libgnome-keyring
   ```

The `libgnome-keyring` package is available in the AUR, so it needs to be built on your system. The `pamac build` command will handle the build process for you.

Please note that `libgnome-keyring` is not actively maintained, and some applications have transitioned to using `gnome-keyring` and `libsecret` instead. However, there might be older applications that still rely on `libgnome-keyring`, which is why you may want to install it.

After completing these steps, you should have `gnome-keyring`, `libsecret`, and `libgnome-keyring` installed on your Manjaro system.

restart your system and try again